# Can't shut/quit Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

Everything was working absolutely perfect with my Android Studio until I decided to change the module name and it simply got stuck. I literally can't do anything about it.

- I can't access any of the File/ Edit/ Navigate/ Tools/ Build/ Analyse (/or any other) options.
  [Everything is unaccessible](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fvHbU.png)
- I can't shut down Android Studio.(Quit application doesn't even work)
- More over I can not shut down my Mac it just displays "Android Studio is interfering"

I have already tried $ adb kill-server but it doesn't work. I didn't find any solution to this problem elsewhere either. So, please help if you've any idea about this.

Comment: try to cancel current dialogs ?

Comment: Kill the process. From the Terminal, that would be the `kill` or possibly `sudo kill` commands. I do not use OS X much, so I do not know if they have a GUI means of killing the process.

Comment: Well deleting the desktop on which the studio was open worked. Anyway, thanks!

Comment: @KritiSharan what do you mean by "deleting the desktop"?

Comment: @MorZa It's a little too late but I will reply to it anyway. So if you maximise the screen of any application on Mac it basically gets added to the desktop tab (you can see this with the 4-finger-up gesture). If you hover over the android studio desktop it shows a minimise icon, clicking on it brings it application to the front on your main desktop and makes it responsive.

Answer (score 28):

Fixed:
Go to Activity Monitor,

Search in list for android studio,

Click on close button below the minimise button in top left corner,

Force quit.

This is for MacOS

Comment: The exact location is /Applications/Utilities/Activity Monitor. Look for android studio and double click on it. Then click on Quit.

Answer (score 4):

The below process perfectly working for me.
Go Applications/Utilities/Activity Monitor then open it.
The select android studio then click left corner cross button
after that, you can see popup please press force quit.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Simply press Escape.
It will close the application after saving the projects currently running.

Answer (score 0):

For Windows
1.Search for Task Manager.
2.See where the android studio is.
3.Right click on android studio in the list of tasks.
4.Select End task.
This will kill your android studio task.